# GWT compiler breaks code into parts

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, gwt

I have a GWT configuration that compiles fine. It also runs fine in all but IE8-10 browsers.

The reason seems to be that the GWT compiler breaks the output into pieces that makes IE throw syntax errors.

Here is part of the compiled code in the XXXXX.cache.html file:

```
...
function bh(){return (new Date).getTime()}
function ch(a){return a}
nT(77,1,{},ah);function dh(){return Di()}
function eh(){return Ei()}
function fh(){return Gi()}
function gh(){return null}
function hh(){return true}
--></script>
<script><!--
function ih(){return true}
function jh(){uk()}
function kh(){vk()}
function ph(a){qh(a)}
function qh(a){wj(a);return a}
...
```

The following snippet is the problem for IE:

```
--></script>
<script><!--
```

Is there a flag i accidentally set on the compiler? Or how did this happen? How do i get rid of it so IE can read my code?

Comment: The script break seems to appear every 1200-1300 lines of js output

Comment: As I remember IE had a limit of script length. I believe this is the reason to break the code. Which version of GWT you are using?

Comment: The project is using 2.5.1 - But I have other modules that compile fine without it and that are much bigger